# jaxrs - Unable to call the webservice : 404 Not Found Error

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have created a simple webservice but I am unable to call it. I get 404 Not found error.

```
package com.fms.mdw.rest;    
@Path("/Search")

public class SearchWebService {

    @POST
    @Path("/searchData")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public FMSResponseInfo getSearchData(SearchDTO searchDTO) {
        System.out.println("Entered the getSearchData()");
        FMSResponseInfo fmsResponseInfo = new FMSResponseInfo();
        List<SearchDetailsDTO> searchDetailsDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            SearchDetailsDTO searchDetailsDto = new SearchDetailsDTO();
            searchDetailsDto.setBarcode("barcode" + i);
            searchDetailsDto.setDocNo("docNo" + i);
            searchDetailsDto.setDocType("docType" + i);
            searchDetailsDtoList.add(searchDetailsDto);
        }
        fmsResponseInfo.setStatus("200");
        fmsResponseInfo.setMessage("Success");
        fmsResponseInfo.setData(searchDetailsDtoList);
        System.out.println("Leaving the getSearchData()");
        return fmsResponseInfo;
    }
}
```

SearchDTO has two fields searchType, searchText both of type string.So the json payload will be {"searchType":"", "searchText":""}

I have registered the webservice in the following manner in web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>LatestFMS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LatestFMS Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.fms.mdw.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LatestFMS Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am able to access the webpages, but I am unable to call the webservice. I am using RESTClient to send post request. The web server is apache tomcat 7 and jersey 2.16 .

The url I am hitting is http://localhost:8082/LatestFMS/rest/Search/searchData.

I am unable to resolve the issue, please help ! ! !

Comment: something , someone ?? can someone suggest where possibly the error can be ???

Comment: Can you access the service using the actual application rather than the RESTClient? Is data being return in the web browser or is that also throwing a 404

Comment: no , i am not able to !!

Comment: What the content type you are sending in the request?

Comment: i am not using Accept Header

Comment: try to add it with `*/*`

Comment: but I never use this, in web service that run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77766/discussion-between-igreen-and-furquan-ahmed).

Comment: When you don't understand why is rejected a query, it's a good practice to trace the query in jersey : 

<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

please enable tracing, and show me the trace. See:  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html